# Volume of cylinder with two different radius and one height

Tags: geometry, volume

[image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WQjpd.png)

If I have top radius $R_1$,bottom radius $R_2$ (where $R_1>R_2$), total height $h$ and another height $p$.

Then how can I calculate the volume of lower part with height of $p$?

I am confused whether it is cylinder? Image is attached above.

Comment: If $R_1 = R_2$, then the figure would be a cylinder. However, if they are different then the figure is that of a "truncated cone"--basically a cone with the pointy end chopped off.

Comment: Additionally, the radius is reduced linearly from $R_1$ to $R_2$ so you can determine the radius of your new base using $R_1$, $R_2$, $p$, and $h$.

Comment: But in a truncated cone the bottom is wider than top.Here top is always wider than bottom.Will it be a truncated cone then?

Comment: This is called a truncated cone.

Answer (score 2):

$\newcommand{\braces}[1]{\left\lbrace\,{#1}\,\right\rbrace}
 \newcommand{\bracks}[1]{\left\lbrack\,{#1}\,\right\rbrack}
 \newcommand{\dd}{\mathrm{d}}
 \newcommand{\ds}[1]{\displaystyle{#1}}
 \newcommand{\expo}[1]{\,\mathrm{e}^{#1}\,}
 \newcommand{\ic}{\mathrm{i}}
 \newcommand{\mc}[1]{\mathcal{#1}}
 \newcommand{\mrm}[1]{\mathrm{#1}}
 \newcommand{\pars}[1]{\left(\,{#1}\,\right)}
 \newcommand{\partiald}[3][]{\frac{\partial^{#1} #2}{\partial #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\root}[2][]{\,\sqrt[#1]{\,{#2}\,}\,}
 \newcommand{\totald}[3][]{\frac{\mathrm{d}^{#1} #2}{\mathrm{d} #3^{#1}}}
 \newcommand{\verts}[1]{\left\vert\,{#1}\,\right\vert}$

> Add and subtract a 'small cone' of height $\ds{h'}$. Then, you evaluate the difference of volume of the 'big' cone and the 'small' one:

$$
{h' \over R_{2}} =
{h \over R_{1} - R_{2}} \implies h' = {R_{2} \over R_{1} - R_{2}}\,h 
$$

---

\begin{align}
V & =
{1 \over 3}\,\pi R_{1}^{2}\pars{h + h'} -
{1 \over 3}\,\pi R_{2}^{2}h' =
{1 \over 3}\,\pi R_{1}^{2}\,{R_{1} \over R_{1} - R_{2}}h -
{1 \over 3}\,\pi R_{2}^{2}\,{R_{2} \over R_{1} - R_{2}}\,h
\\[5mm] & =\
\bbox[8px,border:1px groove navy]{%
{1 \over 3}\,\pi\pars{R_{1}^{2} + R_{1}R_{2} + R_{2}^{2}}h}
\end{align}

Answer (score 1):

Hint. Consider the the volume of the solid as the "sum" of the volumes $\pi R^2(t)\,dt$ of the thin cylinders of radius $R(t)$ and height $dt$:
$$\mbox{Volume of lower part with height of $p$}=V_p=\int_{t=0}^p \pi R^2(t)\,dt$$
Here the function $R(t)$ is linear and goes from $R_2=R(0)$ to $R_1=R(h)$:
$$R(t)=R_2+\frac{(R_1-R_2)t}{h}.$$
It does not matter whether $R_1\geq R_2$ or $R_2\geq R_1$.

P.S. Finally you will find
$$V_p=\frac{\pi p(R_2^2+R(p) R_2+ R(p)^2)}{3}$$
where $\displaystyle R(p)=R_2+\frac{(R_1-R_2)p}{h}$.

For more details see: http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicalFrustum.html

Comment: sorry i can't understand.i have added an image to my question.would you please explain it briefly?

Comment: Md Soman Khan Do you know integrals?

Comment: sorry to say,i don't know integrals

Comment: Do you know the formula of the volume of the truncated cone? http://mathworld.wolfram.com/ConicalFrustum.html

Comment: i know this v=rh(R^2+Rr+r^2)/3   
http://jwilson.coe.uga.edu/emt725/Frustum/Frustum.cone.html

Comment: @Md Soman Khan Then replace h with p and r with R(p) given in my answer. It does not matter if bottom base is smaller than the other base (if you turn it, the volume is the same!)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem its easier to do:
Volume of cylinder=h(pi)r^2
Volume of unequal = (h1(pi)r1^2 + h2(pi)r2^2/2
  Just take the average of both cylinders

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/817523)

Comment: @TheCount It does answer the question. $\LaTeX$ would help as would more clear writing, but the intent is correct.

Comment: @RossMillikan I reviewed the post as I saw fit. You are free to disagree.